# Does js serialize() work with array field names?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I have a form field that looks like this:

```
<input name="cm[3]" value="0.0000">
```

I post it to a secure ajax function using the serializeData function:

```
var formData = $(form).serialize();
console.log(formData);
secureajax.securecall({
    url: '/ajax/quadrants/thresholds-write',
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
    ... etc
```

Note that I am dumping the data to the console...

If I run this code, then immediately on the /ajax/quadrants/thresholds-write page dump the $_POST array, I see my input value on the console (serialized data dump) but the post variable always shows the default value, in this case, "0.0000".

Console snippet:

```
quad_token=b765def8e66df0d473148310175e8a6e&systemsId=12&selectedString=1&cm%5B3%5D=9999...
```

Dump in php of $_POST:

```
Array
(
    [systemsId] => 12
    [selectedString] => 1
    [cm] => Array
        (
            [3] => 0.0000
            [5] => 1.0000
            [7] => 0.0000
```

The default value of CM[3] is 0.0000, but when I type something in such as 9999, I see in js but it is as though the system is reading the value tags, instead of the typed-in value. Or, I was thinking array form field names didn't process but then how come the formatting of the array is fine, just the values get messed up?

Any ideas?

NOTE: secureajax is a custom function that provides CSRF functionality to ajax calls.

Comment: So when you write, "serializeData function", you mean `.serialize()`, right? Anyway the first thing to do is use the browser console to see that secureajax code is actually putting into the outgoing HTTP request.

Comment: Yeah, we may need to see what's in secureajax. It may be expecting all inputs to have a type="" attribute.

Comment: The problem is that you're setting `formData` when the page is loaded. You need to put that code into a function that runs when the user submits the form, so that it gets the updated value of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had multiple divs, showing only one at a time and the array variables didn't account for the multiple forms so the last form's variables were overwriting them. Leaving this here even though it is a bozo error because others might do the same. It is easy to overlook.